# Submit button disabled after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

After clicking the "Contribute" button on my site, an overlay form will appear; however, if someone were to immediately click "Send Pledge" before supplying the info, the button is disabled (as is the Stripe button) for further use. As a result, they can't add a credit card or submit the form; it is permanently disabled until they refresh the page.

How can I change it so that the "Send Pledge" button is still active even after the first click? Please let me know if more information is needed.

A live demo can be found here: http://www.cantedpictures.com/9test/

Otherwise: here is the js:

```
$(function(){
  $("#donateModal").on('show', function() {
    // Fix StripeButton sizing bug on Firefox and IE
    $(".stripe-button-inner, .stripe-button-inner iframe").width(132).height(36);
    // ensure button scrolls with the rest of the page
    $(".stripe-button-inner iframe").css('position', 'relative');
  });

  // Stripe Button Triggers formDomElement.submit().
  // We intercept it and notify user we have received the token
  var paymentForm = $('#payment-form')[0];
  paymentForm.original_submit = paymentForm.submit;
  paymentForm.submit = function() {
    $("#stripe-button-holder .stripe-button-inner").html(
        '<span class="label label-success">
        <i class="icon-ok"></i> Card Added</span>');
    return false;
  };

  $('#payment-form').validate({
      rules: {
      'first-name': {
        minlength: 1,
        required: true
      },
      'last-name': {
        minlength: 1,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      amount: {
        required: true,
        min: 10,
      },
      'tos-agreed': {
        required: true
      }
      },
      messages: {
        'tos-agreed': 'You need to agree to the Terms of Service',
        'first-name': 'Please give us your first name',
        'last-name' : 'Please give us your last name',
        'email'     : 'Please give us your email so that we can contact you',
        'amount'    : 'Please pledge at least $10.'
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, input) {
        $(input).closest('.controls').append(error);
      },
      highlight: function(el) {
        $(el).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
      },
      unhighlight: function(el) {
        $(el).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        // ensure CC info has been entered
        if (! $('[name=stripeToken]').val()) {
          $("#stripe-button-holder").closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
          $("#stripe-button-holder").append('<label class="error">
              Please Add Payment    Information</span>')
          window.location.reload();
        } else {
          form.original_submit();
        }
      }
  });
});//]]>
```

Comment: I think that its not disabled for me (I use chrome btw)

Comment: I should have clarified: the "Contribute" button works, but it's the "Send Pledge" button that doesn't work if you click on it immediately.

After you click "Contribute" and if you immediately click Send Pledge, the button is permanently disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You should identify your button and replace the below `'button'` with `'#myButtonId'`, but once you do you can use

`$('button').prop('disabled', '');`

to remove disabled property.

Comment: Hey Tomanow,

I changed the code the way you said, but it still doesn't work. Do you know where I went wrong? I changed the ID and replaced the disabled property to: $('button').prop('disabled', '');

Comment: Your jQuery selector should be the button id. For example, if your button id is `myButton` do `$('#myButton').prop('disabled', '');` in the callback that you want to trigger the button to be disabled.